# codedeploy no implicit conversion of String into Integer error

Tags: express, cicd

I need help solving this error

This is codeDeploy error

[Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.023162 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{"error_code":5,"script_name":"","message":"no implicit conversion of String into Integer","log":""}"},host_command_identifier:"

```
// appspec.yml

version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  source: /
  destination: /home/ubuntu/build
  overwrite: yes
  file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE



permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu
    pattern: '**'
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu

hooks:

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before-install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after-deploy.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

//scripts/before-install.sh
#!/bin/bash

## 압축 해제할 디렉토리 경로

DESTINATION_DIR="/home/ubuntu/build"

## 압축 파일 경로

ZIP_FILE_PATH="$DESTINATION_DIR/build.zip"

## 압축 해제

unzip -q "$ZIP_FILE_PATH" -d "$DESTINATION_DIR"
unzip_exit_code=$?
if [ $unzip_exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Error: 압축 해제 중 오류가 발생했습니다. 종료 코드: $unzip_exit_code"
exit $unzip_exit_code
else
echo "압축 해제가 성공적으로 완료되었습니다."
fi

## 압축 파일 삭제

rm "$ZIP_FILE_PATH"
rm_exit_code=$?
if [ $rm_exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Error: 압축 파일 삭제 중 오류가 발생했습니다. 종료 코드: $rm_exit_code"
exit $rm_exit_code
else
echo "압축 파일 삭제가 성공적으로 완료되었습니다."
fi

I tried anything . please help me .

Answer (score 0):

JSON payload 에러가 난걸로 미루어볼때
우선 인던트랑 문법이 안맞는것 같습니다

According to your error message, I think your yml has some indent and syntax error

### AS-IS

appspec.yml

```
files:
  source: /
  destination: /home/ubuntu/build
  overwrite: yes
  file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
```

### TO-BE

```
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/build
    overwrite: yes
    file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
```